# How to acces the comment object's "reaction" property?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Office currently offers a new functionality to give likes for comments. Thus in MS Office VBA API documentation I can't find a reaction object or a comment object's reaction property (property or object for reactions (likes) of comments).

Is there a way to access this feature via VBA API? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find comment reactions in the XML of a saved Word file (if you unzip it) - see *word/CommentsExtensible.xml* but it looks like there's no VBA way to get there?  See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oreactxml/915aac43-6f96-43fa-8e1a-6fe5eb3cb1fc

Comment: Much of Modern Comments does not seem to be in the object model and accessible via vba. I suspect that it will not be.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your replies. If anyone has an update or finds a way, let us know!